# PUG create command doesn't respond

Tags: python, discord.py

So I need to detect a link, but I'm not sure how. The error that gets printed is "Attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'.

```
@bot.command()
async def create(ctx):
  embed1 = discord.Embed()
  embed1.add_field(name="To start, send your vip link.", value="**__MUST__ be a roblox football fusion link, sending any other link will result in a 48h mute, as well as a loss of your PUG Host role.**", inline=True)
  url = '\http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'
  embed2 = discord.Embed()
  embed2.add_field(name="New PUG!", value=f"{url}", inline=True)
  msg_sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
  await url.send(embed=embed2)
```

By the way, it's mean to be a two-part command.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with `url.send()`? Did you mean to write `ctx.send()`? `url` is just a string, not a class, that's where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, this might be what you're looking for:

```py
@client.command()
async def create(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed (
        title = 'To start, send your vip link.',
        description = '__MUST__ be a roblox football fusion link, sending any other link will result in a 48h mute, as well as a loss of your PUG Host role.'
    )
    message = await ctx.send(embed = embed)

    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author

    # This function is used to check if the message received is a valid URL
    def checkURL(url):
        regex = 'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'

        return re.match(regex, url) is not None

    try:
        url = await client.wait_for('message', check = check, timeout = 60.0)
        
        if (checkURL(url.content)):
            embed = discord.Embed (
                title = 'New PUG!',
                description = url.content
            )
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send('Sorry, that is not a valid roblox football fusion link.')
    except:
        await message.delete()
```

**Note:** remember to import the `re` module.

**Note:** For the `regex` part, I just used the string that was in the question. You'll have to refine it more to check if the url matches with a specific domain. For example you can check for only *google.com* links. Learn more about `regex` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).